# GMail doesn't display X-ALT-DESC parameter value of iCalendar invite

Tags: java, gmail, icalendar, vcalendar

We need to inform our customers about upcoming appointments. So I send them iCalendar invites in order to create appointments in their calendars. The example of iCalendar invite can be seen below.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//NONSGML Scheduler//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
TRANSP:OPAQUE    
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20160504T235656Z
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20160509T090000
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20160509T100000
SUMMARY:Appointment with Terrance
CREATED:20160504T235655Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20160504T235655Z
DTSTAMP:20160504T235656Z
UID:appointment-101@gmail.com
TZID:America/New_York
SEQUENCE:0
LOCATION:Sunset blvd.\, Brooklyn\, NY 11203
ORGANIZER;CN=Barrimore:MAILTO:mailer@gmail.com
ATTENDEE;CN=Barrimore;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=FALSE;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL:mailto:aleh......@gmail.com
STATUS:CONFIRMED
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<html><body>Barrimore,<br><br>An appointment with Terrance was recently created or updated by you or your staff.<br><br>You can see your updated calendar by signing in at: <a href="https://localhost">https://localhost</a>.<br><br>For help signing in or general support issues, please email support@gmail.com.<br><br>Thank you.</body></html>
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

So the problem is that GMail doesn't display html contents of X-ALT-DESC parameter. Curious, that everything's ok with Hotmail - it displays event panel with "Accept", "Ignore" buttons and formatted html message from X-ALT-DESC. GMail displays event info panel only.

Answer (score 0):

The `X-ALT-DESC` is a MSFT specific extension (see [MSND on iCalendar/X-ALT-DESC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee237480%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx))
you can check the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545) to double check.

Given hotmail relation to Microsoft, it makes sense for them to support it and probably also some sense as to why Google would not support a MSFT proprietary feature.